# "Flourish" or "flourishing" (or something else?)

Tags: word-choice

> The negotiation was not successful until 70s but the British government eventually accepted to release the areas in exchange for other areas.
>   Hence, the transportation and financial developments are implemented quickly in Admiralty, making our city more ***flourish***. ... (flourish? flourishing?)

"Flourish" can be a verb or a noun instead of an adjective. Should I turn "flourish" into "flourishing"? I am not familiar with this word and it is not easy to pronounce. Can another word be used to replace it?

Comment: Writing *transportation* is not really necessary. Writing the word *transport* will be sufficient, with no change in meaning http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/transport_1?q=transport

Comment: *Flourish* is only a verb or noun; it is not used as an adjective.

Comment: It's true that there's a suffix *-ish* which forms adjectives, which comes from Old English *-isc*.  But although it looks the same, this is not the same *ish*; this *ish*, which you can find in *abolish*, *banish*, *brandish*, *cherish*, *demolish*, *embellish*, *establish*, *finish*, ***flourish***, *furnish*, *garnish*, *impoverish*, *languish*, *nourish*, *perish*, *polish*, *ravish*, *refurbish*, *relinquish*, and *replenish*, comes from Old French *-iss-* and forms verbs rather than adjectives.

Comment: I would prefer "until the 1970s" (or maybe 1870s?) to "until 70s". Instead of "are implemented" probably "were implemented" could be better, because you are not writing about today but the 1970s, don't you?

Comment: "in Admiralty" should be *in* ***the*** *Admiralty*. See this http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-admiralty?q=admiralty

Comment: @Tristan - Admiralty is also a place name in Hong Kong. Should I add "the"?

Comment: Casper Li, I didn't know that. In that case, you would not need to add **the** but, you would need to make it clear that you are talking about Admiralty the place. You could do that just before the quote in your question or, adjust the relevant line to something like *in Admiralty, Hong Kong,*.

Answer (score 1):

Saying **more flourishing** would be grammatically correct, but a better construction would be simply to say

> [...] are implemented quickly, [...] making our city flourish.

Comment: I might have said, "*allowing* our city to flourish"